How works Model in Spring MVC
In my understanding Spring MVC Model isn`t a Singleton. So, every time I ask for a Model I get a fresh one. OK, but please check next code:
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLogin(Model model) {
        Login l =  new Login();
        model.addAttribute("login", l);
        log.info("GET - Model hashcode: "+model.hashCode());
        log.info("GET - Login hashcode: "+l.hashCode());
        return "login";
    }

    // Check for Credentials
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@ModelAttribute(name = "login") Login login, Model model) {
        String uname = login.getUsername();
        String pass = login.getPassword();
        
        //---------------------------------------------------------
        log.info("POST - Model hashcode: "+model.hashCode());
        if(model.containsAttribute("login")){
            Login l = (Login)model.getAttribute("login");
            log.info("POST - Login hashcode: "+l.hashCode());
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------
        
        if (uname.equals("Admin")&& pass.equals("Admin@123")) {
            model.addAttribute("uname", uname);
            model.addAttribute("pass", pass);
            return "welcome";
        }
        model.addAttribute("error", "Incorrect Username & Password");
        return "login";

    }
}

Here a login object is added to the model in the showLogin() method. Then in the login() method a model is injected. Being that a model is not a Singleton I can understand that its hashCode be different from showLogin() and login() methods. However, the strange thing is that the Login object also has different hash codes in both methods.
The only explanation I found is that Spring Boot is somehow cloning the Model object, in login() method, and including inside a fresh Login instance to bound with form data.
The question is: Am I right? Is Spring recreating a model object, after the post  was submitted and adding inside a new Login instance with the data entered by the user?
